# How to convert i32 to a string representing the ASCII character

Tags: rust, ascii

I'm re-doing a project in Rust this weekend and I need to convert an i32 to an ASCII character using it as the character code. All I have so far is a monstrous `match` that I'm hiding at the end of a file. Unfortunately, `std::ascii` does not support this conversion. Currently I'm just looking for a less ridiculous/more Rust-like(?) way to do this.

```
fn to_ascii(i: &i32) -> String {
    let a = match *i {
        0 => "NUL",
        1 => "SOH",
        2 => "STX",
        // ...
        125 => "}",
        126 => "~",
        127 => "DEL",
        _ => "",
    }
    a
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you don't need to return a `String`, a `&'static str` is sufficient. Second, you could simply set up an array of `&'static str`s with all code representations you like, and use `.get(_)` to get the relevant string slices, as long as all your char codes are consecutive (which they should be if I have my ASCII right). Even if they aren't, you can always put empty strings in the gaps.

The code should look like the following:

```
const CHARS: [&'static str; 128] = ["NUL", "SOH", "STX", .., "DEL"];

fn get_char_code(c: i32) -> &'static str {
    CHARS.get(c as usize).unwrap_or("")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess since ascii values don't really ever change I'd be good using `&'static str`

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I wouldn't mind the `match` version. The only tweak is that you don't need a temporary variable. I'd encourage you to follow [llogiq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35833580/155423) and return a `&'static str`, which your caller could convert to a `String` if needed:

```
fn get_char_code(i: &i32) -> &'static str {
    match *i {
        0 => "NUL",
        1 => "SOH",
        2 => "STX",
        // ...
        125 => "}",
        126 => "~",
        127 => "DEL",
        _ => "",
    }
}
```

Additionally, I'd **highly** recommend not using the word "ASCII" in this code. Most programmers associate an "ASCII character" as a single `u8` worth of data that maps to specific characters, punctuation, or control codes.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `format!` macro to convert `char` to `String`:

```
fn to_ascii(i: &i32) -> String {
    match *i {
        x@0...127 => format!("{:?}", x as u8 as char),
        _ => "".into(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    for x in 0x09..0x12 {
        print!("{} ", to_ascii(&x));
    }
    println!("");
    //'\t' '\n' '\u{b}' '\u{c}' '\r' '\u{e}' '\u{f}' '\u{10}' '\u{11}' 

    for x in 0x30..0x40 {
        print!("{} ", to_ascii(&x));
    }
    println!("");
    //'0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' ':' ';' '<' '=' '>' '?' 
}
```

---

This returns `'\u{0}'` instead of `"NUL"` i.e. escape codes instead of an abbreviation. If you do not like how it looks, you can use a huge match or string array.

Actually you need to redefine only 33 control code characters. For other printable characters you can still use `format!`:

```
fn to_ascii(i: &i32) -> String {
    match *i {
        x@0...32 => ["NUL", "SOH", "STX", ..., "SPC"][x as usize].into(),
        x@33...126 => format!("{}", x as u8 as char),
        127 => "DEL".into(),
        _ => "".into(),
    }
}
```

For a more Rust-like way, you may use smart pointers like [`Cow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) as the return type:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn to_ascii(i: &i32) -> Cow<'static, str> {
    match *i {
        x@0...32 => ["NUL", "SOH", "STX", ..., "SPC"][x as usize].into(),
        x@32...126 => format!("{}", x as u8 as char).into(),
        127 => "DEL".into(),
        _ => "".into(),
    }
}
```

Read more about `Cow` usage [here](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/05/29/creating-a-rust-function-that-returns-string-or-str.html).

Comment: How would this return `"NUL"` for 0 (or any other of the multiple character mappings?)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast as below:

```
println!("{}", 'A' as i8); // prints 65
println!("{}", 65 as char); // prints 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `i32`, you can use `u32` with [`from_u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/fn.from_u32.html):

```rust
use std::char::from_u32;

fn main() -> Result<(), u32> {
   let n = 0x21;
   let c = from_u32(n).ok_or(n)?;
   println!("{}", c);
   Ok(())
}
```